# Flat KNN line and low accuracy

Tags: python, database, algorithm, prediction, knn

For a project at school we are supposed to predict if a stock will go up or down based on variables that we chose. We used many different algorithm in class, and I'm quite confused on which one to use with my data, but I'd like to make KNN works. The problem I encounter is that it my KNN graph is a straight line, and thus I can't use the elbow method to find the lowest error rate. The ultimate goal would be to have a good accuracy, but if it implies changing all the database...

Please, find attached a screen of my database so you know what kind of data i'm dealing with : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLsps.jpg (93 rows for each columns, i.e each month from 2015 to september 2022)

what i'm dealing with my KNN graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhm3A.png

and my accuracy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I4eP.jpg

I am pretty sure that something is wrong in there, doesn't my confusion matrix have little data compared to my database?
(im sorry between excel and google colab, not very sure on how/what to paste here relevantly)

I tried to basically copy & paste what we've done in my course, which is:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler.fit(df.drop('direction',axis=1))

stand_features = scaler.transform(df.drop('direction',axis=1))

df_stand = pd.DataFrame(stand_features,columns=df.columns[:-1])

df_stand.head()
```

```
# import library
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(stand_features,df['direction'],test_size=0.25)
```

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(x_test)
```

```
error_rate = []

for i in range(1,40):
  knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
  knn.fit(x_train,y_train)
  pred_i = knn.predict(x_test)
  error_rate.append(np.mean(pred_i != y_test))
```

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(range(1,40),error_rate,color='blue', linestyle='dashed', marker='o', markerfacecolor='red', markersize=10)

plt.title('Error Rate vs K Value')

plt.xlabel('K')
plt.ylabel('Error rate')
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)
knn.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(x_test)

print('WITH K=2')
print('\n')
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print('\n')

print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

I was expecting a KNN graph like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTfmW.jpg with an accuracy between 45 and 75 but I'm having a flat KNN curve and a even more terrible accuracy than expected

Any recommendation?

Thank you very much, sorry i'm new here